# Unknown exotic weapon

Tags: destiny

While I was playing yesterday evening, I got a message on the screen similar to "RandomPlayer found 'the recombinant gun'", with the "the recombinant gun" in yellow text, as if it was an exotic weapon. The problem is, the word is not recombinant, and unfortunately I cant remember it, but it was something along those lines.

This occured on Mars, during a patrol, when I was in the Scablands.

I cant find any reference to this at all. Has anyone else seen it / any information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*any* exotic and legendary item obtained will appear in the chat feed for all to see.

this includes shards, weapons, engrams, and quest items.

What you probably saw was the player recieved [An Enthusiastic Gun](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/A_Voice_in_the_Wilderness) from the Exotic bounty

Comment: ah, I'd say its "A Recalcitrant Gun", which is mentioned on that page.

Comment: @jasper Given the location in which he saw it, you are correct. It was the first step of the Exotic Weapon Bounty for Super Good Advice.